# Сохранение вкладки Sublime при потере фокуса?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

что нужно сделать, чтобы при переключении вкладок или переключении из редактора на что-нибудь другое автоматически сохранялось содержимое активной вкладки (`CTRL + S`).
Пробовал в `Preferences -> Settings -> User` добавить    `"save_on_focus_lost": true,`
что-то не помогает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: только что проверил на ubuntu 18. работает без проблем!

Comment: попробуйте временно удалить из этого файла всё, оставить только `{"save_on_focus_lost": true}`.

Comment: когда Sublime долго работает, бывает, что эта опция не работает. Лечу перезагрузки Sublime